# Laravel - How to rollback migration with foreign key

Tags: laravel, migration

I am trying to rollback the migrations in laravel, but keep getting "Cannot drop table referenced by a foreign key restraint". I changed the dates and the times, but Laravel still thinks that the mother table (ie: the table in which the other tables reference to) is at the top. Any suggestions?

Comment: check which table is referencing any field on the table you are trying to delete. in all cases the migration orders are not right. You can check it by creating a new database and migrating a new installation, you will get errors.

Comment: I changed the migration order, and was wondering if there was any way to force other tables to be migrated first. For whatever reason, the migration runs the mother table first, even if it is listed at the bottom of the migration folder

Comment: That is not possible, if, by name, it is listed at the end, it will be run at the end

Comment: There's no other way to force the migrations to be run in a different order other than simply changing the time?

Comment: Migrations are run following the naming order, so how you see them listed in your IDE, the are going to be run like that (from top to bottom), so you should change the name of the migrations, but be very careful as the migrations run are stored inside the `migrations` table, and then you will end up having migrations (names) in there that do not exist, confusing anyone if you have issues in the future and need to check migration steps

Answer (score 3):

Changing migration order is not recommended, because you can screw yourself over with foreign keys among other things (migrations that depend on other migrations to be run first for example).

In any case,  whenever you have a migration that creates a foreign key, you should drop it in the down() method.

```php
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('children', function (Blueprint $table) {
        ...
        $table->foreignId('parent_id')->constrained('parents');
        ...
    });
}

public function down(): void
{
    Schema::table('children', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign(['parent_id']);
    });

    Schema::dropIfExists('children');
}
```